# Compare two bind element and change cell color

Tags: wpf, compare

please tell me how to make a value1 cell red  if value1 >= value2 and green when value1 < value2

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGridTextColumn Width="20" Header="value1" Binding="{Binding value1}" />
<DataGridTextColumn Width="38" Header="value2 " Binding="{Binding value2 }">
      <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
             <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                  <Style.Triggers>
                      .........................
                      .........................
                      .........................
                  </Style.Triggers>
             </Style>
      </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Both columns have binding to value1.. assume that's a typo?

Comment: Sorry, I made ​​a mistake already corrected

Answer (score 5):

I see two ways to do this,

1. You can create a new property `ValueColor` in your entity which is bound to this grid, and returns the correct color.
2. You can bind Background of TextBlock with [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) to Value1 and Value2 with a converter that returns the color.

Here is an example

create MultiValueConverter like this

```
public class ValuesToColorConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            int value1 = (int)values[0];
            int value2 = (int)values[1];
            return value1 >= value2 ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.Green;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

And use this xaml to show colors

```
<Window.Resources>
    <WpfApplication1:ValuesToColorConverter x:Key="colorConverter" />
  </Window.Resources>
  <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="...">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="20" Header="value1" Binding="{Binding value1}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="38" Header="value2 " Binding="{Binding value2 }">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Setter Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource colorConverter}">
                                        <Binding Path="value1"/>
                                        <Binding Path="value2"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
```

By the way, you have another error too, you should add GridColumns in  collection istead of as Grid Content, use my xaml and it will work

Hope this helps

Comment: Will you please tell more, and maybe you can show an example with code

Comment: You are wellcome @longtrades, don't forgot to mark post as answer if it helps, otherwise no one will answer your questions in the future